# Telerik controls not rendering correctly with ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated app pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, telerik, application-pool

We have a webform that uses several Telerik controls. When I switch to `ASP.NET v4.0 Classic`, the controls are rendered correctly. When I switch to `ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated`, the controls are not rendered. I assume it has to do with permissions.

Unfortunately, it needs to stay as `ASP.NET v4.0 Integrated`, so what would I need to do so that the controls are rendered correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that `Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd` handler (in `system.webServer`) was registered incorrectly with `preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0` in web.config:

Instead of this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ChartImage_axd"/>
        <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd"/>
        <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx"/>
        <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx"/>
        <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
        <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd"/>
        <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

It should be without `runtimeVersionv2.0`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
          <remove name="ChartImage_axd"/>
          <add name="ChartImage_axd" path="ChartImage.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.ChartHttpHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
          <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd"/>
          <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
          <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx"/>
          <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
          <remove name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx"/>
          <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.ashx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.RadUploadProgressHandler" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
          <remove name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd"/>
          <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

On an additional note (at least for me) if the app is running under `asp.net v4.0 Classic`, the section `<httpHandlers>` (under `<system.web>`) is used. If `asp.net v4.0 Integrated`, then `<handlers>` (under `<system.webServer>`) is used.

Comment: It's good you have found that, it's easy to miss. Also, sorry for not being clear enough with my first paragraph, integrated mode always reads system.webServer, classic mode and old IIS versions read system.web, as you have discovered.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the HTTP handles in the web.config are not registered properly, newer IIS versions and modes read them from the system.webServer section: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-registering-the-httphandlers-on-windows-vista-iis-7-integrated-mode.html.

If this is not the case, make sure you don't have script errors. Off the top of my head, here are a few reasons:

you are under .NET4 and using IE10/11, so you will get MS AJAX script errors: http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11.

for some reason the webresources fail: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/introduction-web-resources-troubleshooting.html. Try the CDN for scripts or skins that is offered, depending on what breaks if you can't fix it (assuming this is the reason).

see if the application pool user has permissions to access and modify the folder where your site is (this is done in Windows, not in your project). Make sure it has, at least, Modify rights.